# .js library "Uncaught ReferenceError: numjs is not defined"

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to do use [NumJS](https://github.com/numjs/numjs) but I cannot understand why this error is coming up.  The file "numjs.js" is included locally with the HTML.  This is the code that I have been using to troubleshoot the problem:

```
<head>
    <script src="numjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial">
    <font size=5>
        <b>Test</b>
    </font>
    <script>
        a = numjs.arange(0.,1.,6);
        console.log(a);
    </script>
</body>
```

Error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: numjs is not defined

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Well for one thing your <b> tag needs to be closed

Comment: Right now, the script tag is searching numjs.js in the same folder as the html. In what folder (relative to the html) is numjs.js located ?

Comment: Also you have your <body> tag twice

Comment: <head>
            <script src="numjs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:Arial">
        <font size=5>
            <b>Test</b>
        </font>
        <script>
            a = numjs.arange(0.,1.,6);
            console.log(a);
        </script>
    </body>

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numjs) it's `nj`, not `numjs`.

```js
a = nj.arange(0.,1.,6);
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numjs/0.13.1/numjs.js"></script>
<font size=5>
    <b>Test</b>
</font>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.